# Running multiple version of code

Tags: version-control, development-process

How should I set up my project when I want to run the present version of a class against previous versions? I'm interested in issues related to code organization, file naming, and source control.

I have a stable version A of my code, and am working on some accuracy improvements for version B. (It's a forecasting model in Python, but my question is perhaps broader than either of those things.)

I want to be able to run both of these versions of code at the same time in at least these two situations:

1. **Testing.** To test the new changes, I'd like to run a test data set through both version A and version B. Version B ought to give more accurate results (and if not it needs improved/fixed). In the future I'd start on version C, and I'd like to be able to test C alongside B (and maybe A).
2. **Speed/accuracy tradeoffs.** Each version is intended to offer an incremental improvement in forecasting accuracy, although this will typically require greater complexity and processing. For some purposes I may prefer a faster answer, even if it were less accurate. In those cases I would default to an earlier version for a quick-and-dirty answers.

I have seen suggestions for **feature flags**. So I'd have one class, but I'd specify if I want the A or B (or C) logic. I think this would get messy quickly. It would be easier to read if I had a version with just the A code.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but we need some more info. Is it just one class? Multiple classes? Are the classes in question algorithms that calculate values, or are they collaborator classes that coordinate the efforts of multiple other objects?

Comment: Do you need to run different versions for comparison purposes, like A-B testing? Is this something that is only done in development? Will you keep multiple versions of this code indefinitely? What about version control like Git doesn't solve this problem?

Comment: Right now I've just got the one class that is mostly algorithmic (input some data and it spits out a new data set). Each "version" could have an algorithm similar to other versions or radically different.

Comment: Maybe Git is the right answer. I had viewed source control as preserving a project's history (diachronic?) vs. my current idea of multiple active "versions." But that may be my own lack of understanding.

Comment: Version control is not necessarily the right answer, nor is it the wrong answer. We need more information. Can you answer the questions I posted above?

Comment: Be careful using the term *version*. In software development, it implies a temporal aspect; i.e. you start with a "thing", and the thing evolves over time as its requirements change (replacing the original), so dates or incrementing numbers are used to disambiguate  between versions of that ***same*** thing.   If what you're talking about is creating entirely ***different*** independent forms altogether, then that (in software terms at least) does not really fit what most developers would understand to be a "version".   That may seem nitpicky, but inaccurate terminology often causes confusion.

Comment: I suggest you delete this question while you still can

Answer (score 2):

Having written a lot of computational software by myself, I have been in your shoes several times. From that, I think I can give you some hints.

First, let us call "A, B and C" different *algorithms* for solving the same problem. You need to clarify first if you want

1. A, B, C all in the same version of your program (version like "version 3.0", for example), each one available side-by-side with the other algorithms, or
2. A in version 1.0, B only in version 2.0 and C only available in version 3.0

The first approach makes it easier to switch between all the available algorithms at runtime (by some parameter, like a command line parameter). It gives you the possibility to maintain and evolve A, B and C in parallel, fix bugs and add improvements like user interface extensions, logging, improved error handling and other new featuers to the program to all of them over time.

The drawback is that it becomes moree challenging in regards to maintenance and evolvement, since it will require more effort to maintain all the algorithm variants over time. Hence, it is important to refactor constantly any commonalities between the algorithms into shared classes, sticking to the DRY principle, otherwise one will undoubtly run into a maintenance nightmare. To make this possible, writing automated regression tests is usually a must.

The second approach is most effective when you only want to maintain the "latest and the greatest" version of the code, but to run the different versions in parallel, you should establish a proper versioning and release process.

That means:

- When you have "version 1.0" with algorithm A ready, "release it" (that may simply mean to copy all executable files over to a "production 1.0" folder, nothing complicated, in Python I guess this is mostly identical with the source code). Make sure the program has a version label "1.0" somewhere inside and writes this version somewhere into the set of output files, so you can always find out from which version the output was produced. Make also sure to tag the related sources with a label "1.0" in your source control system.
- Now, you improve algorithm A, so it evolves and finally becomes B, and when you are satisfied, release "version 2.0" just the same way: version label 2.0 inside the program tag 2.0 in your SCCs, copy files to "production 2.0"
- Repeat this with C and version 3.0, and so on.

It should be self-evident that both approaches allow you to run A, B, and C in parallel, side-by-side. The second approach aims for less maintenance, but when you extend version 3.0 with an improved feature which is orthogonal to the algorithm itself, the former versions will not get that feature automatically.

In short, this is a trade-off. And it is not "black-and-white". You may also decide to develop version 1.0 only with algorithm "A", and version 2.0 with algorithms "B and C" side-by-side. It depends on what you need, so pick your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use version control, just check out and build different versions in different directories. If you're not using version control, start doing it now.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of having "
different versions"
is for unit testing, it's not a good idea using the output of one program as the expected value to compare the output of the program being tested. That would mean you are testing two versions at a time. You should use mockup that return literals instead.

In the other hand I believe you are not dealing with a version control problem, but with a software pattern problem. You need to have different working algorithms and change them at runtime, like State, Template and Command.